# Azure mobileserviceclient login returns authentication error(401)

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I currently have a login flow with facebook that is working 100% and I just added Google into the equation. I wrote the code so that my google provider tokens are formatted and cached in the same way as my facebook tokens. My code gets the facebook and google tokens and does the folling: (the following example is for the google login):

```
        USER_GOOGLE_TOKEN = new JsonObject();
        USER_GOOGLE_TOKEN.addProperty("access_token", accessToken);
        cacheProviderToken(USER_GOOGLE_TOKEN.toString());
        setCurrentProvider("google");
```

Then, in my authentication method in the activity, here is how I mobileserviceclient.login:

```
 MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = null;
        if (getCurrentProvider().equals("facebook")){
            provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook;
        } else if (getCurrentProvider().equals("google")) {
            provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google;
        }


        token.addProperty("access_token", googleToken);
        ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> mLogin = mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, getProviderToken());
```

The problem is that Facebook works and Google produces a 401 unauthorized.
The specific error I get (before the future returns failed), is: W/DefaultRequestDirector: `Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}. Azure logs show that it is a 401 unauthorized.

I am successfully printing the Google-Sign-In token and formatting it in the same way as my facebook tokens before trying to use them. Are my google keys wrong? I regenerated them once already and I tried setting origions to https, I tried different key combos, and I even got rid of my google-services.json(apparently its not needed). I did not use the client key that was generated on [this google doc](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In).

Another question here is how does the authentication settings of my Azure Mobile App come into play? I had originally configured my facebook before migrating from a MobileService to MobileApp, and now I do not need to use the "turnkey authentication" feature for it to work. I went ahead and entered my app key and secret for facebook, but it definitely works regardless of whether or not this is enabled. Is this a necessary feature for oauth?

Also, Depending on the token format on Login and the On/Off status of the AUthentication feature, the errror: `W/DefaultRequestDirector: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}`
, will have some text in the curly brackets about the azure endpoint.

Thank you so much if you can help. Such a picky issue here.

Comment: Can you elaborate the last one - about azure endpoint? That error is basically 401, and should not have nothing with the Azure.

Comment: In mobile app authentication,  when I set the setting,  "what to do when not authenticated",  the curly braces contain information about "bearers". I also have some new information for you. Last night I went into the classic portal and saw the Facebook strings from when I set up authentication under the Identity tab of the mobile service. I Tried hard coding the Google values in the  configure area next to the Facebook values since the identify tab is gone.  It did not work despite disabling mobile app Auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Service Authentication / Authorization is incompatible with a migrated Mobile Service and must remain off.

To update Authentication settings with a migrated Mobile Service, you set the app settings.  For facebook, that's `MS_FacebookAppID` and `MS_FacebookAppSecret`.  For Google, that's `MS_GoogleClientID` and `MS_GoogleClientSecret`.

For reference, check out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/#authentication

Comment: Thanks. Your advice was critical, but did not solve the problem.[This blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/) contains an author comment in response (post #2) to a similar problem. Not sure how to follow his instructions, but I tried doing a mobile service login (google provider) without a token parameter and it successfully generated a user in my backend. I did successfully receive a token and an access code from the Google response, so is it getting them automatically? I did not provide them to the mobile service...

Comment: If you do a mobile services login without a token, then the backend negotiates the login, presenting the normal UI to the user.  You can also do a client login (where you use the IdP SDK and then submit the token during the mobile services login) - either one should work.

Comment: So if I want to pass a token or auth code (from google) as a parameter in the login method of a mobile service client, what should the format be? I tried everything and it always returned errors as noted in the blog that I linked. I tried using  a json object with different fields, the token string alone, server auth code alone, etc. In the end I left it blank and was able to generate a new authenticated mobile service user and a user in my backend. What I am worried about is that perhaps since i am not supplying an oauth token, the MSclient ID will not always be the same/unique? Is this true?

Comment: You can only authenticate to one provider in Mobile Services.  You can log in to both providers in Azure App Service - that's a new feature of the auth capabilities, however.